# How to remove extra space in an iframe generated DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying an iframe on my web page. However there is extra space like `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` in the generated DOM. How can I remove it? I used jQuery like this. Didn't work. Thanks.

jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    let $iframe = $("iframe[name=previewIframe]");

    $iframe.on('load',function() {
        $iframe.contents().find("body #gwd-ad").text().replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
    });
});
```

HTML
[image]

Comment: Did you get an access denied error in the console? Then that is the reason

Comment: There is no errors on console.

Comment: Does this show the spaces? `$iframe.on('load',function() {
        var text = $iframe.contents().find("body #gwd-ad").text(); console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
    });`

Comment: the text variable is the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$iframe.on('load',function() {
    var $ad = $iframe.contents().find("#gwd-ad");
    $ad.html($ad.find("a").html())
});
```